# Mandlebrot task class

Tags: java, complex-numbers

I'm trying to implement mandelbrot however it my main classes it draws a single color because all of the iteration counts are staying at zero. I've looked for the cause of this for a while and couldn't determine what is causing it to do this. I looked for other sources however their approach was completely different. All of the drawing is done in the main class and the magnitude add and multiply methods were created in a third class.

```
package edu.ycp.cs201.mandelbrot;

public class MandelbrotTask implements Runnable {
private double x1, y1, x2, y2;
private int startCol, endCol, startRow, endRow;
private int[][] iterCounts;

public MandelbrotTask(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,
                      int startCol, int endCol, int startRow, int endRow,
                      int[][] iterCounts) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.startCol = startCol;
    this.endCol = endCol;
    this.startRow = startRow;
    this.endRow = endRow;
    this.iterCounts = iterCounts;
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = startRow; i < endRow; i++) {
        for (int j = startCol; j < endCol; j++) {
            Complex c = getComplex(i, j);
            int iterCount = computeIterCount(c);
            iterCounts[i][j] = iterCount;
        }
    }
}

// TODO: implement getComplex and computeIterCount methods
public Complex getComplex(int x, int y) {
    //return new Complex (x, y);
    double col = (double) endCol - (double) startCol;
    double row = (double) endRow - (double) startRow;
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;
    return new Complex(x1 + dx / col * x, y1 + dy / row * y);
}

public int computeIterCount(Complex complex) {
    //Zo is initially 0+0i
    Complex z = new Complex(0,0);
    //# of iterations
    int count = 0;
    //while z has magnitude of less than 2 and iteration counts have not 
    exceeded MAX
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        //iterate complex number
        z = z.multiply(z).add(complex);
        //if magnitude of complex number is >2 stop
        if (z.getMagnitude() > 2) {
            break;
        }
        //increment count
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code directly from source? The code as provided wouldn't compile due an exposed comment in the `computeIterCount` function, right above the for loop.

Comment: Are you sure you’re calling the `run()` method of MandlebrotTask?